# jQuery window resize fires alert, doesn't fire function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have the following pieces of code in my footer:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
      var maxHeight1 = 0; $(".header-primary").each(function(){ if ($(this).height() > maxHeight1) { maxHeight1 = $(this).height(); } }); $(".header-primary").height(maxHeight1);
      var maxHeight2 = 0; $(".header-secondary").each(function(){ if ($(this).height() > maxHeight2) { maxHeight2 = $(this).height(); } }); $(".header-secondary").height(maxHeight2);
    });
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(window).resize(function($){
      alert('I fire');
      var maxHeight1 = 0; $(".header-primary").each(function(){ if ($(this).height() > maxHeight1) { maxHeight1 = $(this).height(); } }); $(".header-primary").height(maxHeight1);
      var maxHeight2 = 0; $(".header-secondary").each(function(){ if ($(this).height() > maxHeight2) { maxHeight2 = $(this).height(); } }); $(".header-secondary").height(maxHeight2);
    });
</script>
```

The first piece does its job properly. When I refresh/open the page, the elements that have the CSS classes mentioned inside this JS code, have the same size (of the biggest one).

When it comes to the window.resize part, it doesn't work at all. I've tried all kinds of wrappers to satisfy Firebug, but even when it doesn't display an error, the script still doesn't work. The alert included for testing purposes works, so window.resize fires properly.

I usually find solutions using the search engine, but this one is an exception. :(

HTML:

```
<div class="block">

  <div class="block-big-item">

    <h3 class="header-primary">BIG ITEM</h3>

  </div>

  <div class="block-small-items">

    <div class="block-small-item">
      <h3 class="header-secondary">SMALL ITEM</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="block-small-item">
      <h3 class="header-secondary">SMALL ITEM</h3>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Please post your HTML and any other relevant information

Comment: HTML is not an issue. I've said the code works as intended in the first snippet. It doesn't work in the second one. I want to know how to adjust it so it works on window.resize too, because the results are good.

Comment: HTML will help us reproduce the problem. Please see [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). And if I ask for something you have to be sure I'm asking for it for a reason :-)

Comment: In your ready handler, you have set all those elements to the same height. In your resize handler, you now again try to find the “maximum” of all those identical heights … so you are setting only the height they _all_ already have, for _all_ of those items.

Comment: This should probably not be using JS at all. Getting elements to take equal height is rather trivial these days with flexbox.

Comment: @misorude - not if they're in separate but adjacent containers. The flexboxes within one container are indeed the same height. But next to this there is another block with another data and their flexboxes are also the same height, but not the same as in the previous block. That's why I have to use these headings to 'blow up' all of them to make all the boxes in all the blocks the same height so it looks consistent.

Comment: (What you are explaining now, is the reason why you should include example HTML with your question to begin with.) _“But next to this there is another block […]”_ - if they are next to each other, they could probably be put into an additional flex container as well - to make both of those blocks the same height.

Comment: @misorude  - HTML added. As you can see, these are two-part blocks, the length (and the number of lines) of the text is not predictable, so these blocks, existing one after another, won't look consistent without JS. I focused on the headings as the basis to make them all look consistent.

Comment: Are the blocks _next to_ each other and supposed to have the same height, or are they _below_ each other? And what do you actually want to achieve here, have both of those blocks take the same height? (Your JS solution right now does not seem suited to that purpose to begin with, because you are calculating two _different_ max heights here.)

Comment: @misorude 
1) Thanks for your patience! :) 
2) The blocks may be adjacent to or below one other, depends on the width of your screen (responsive CSS)
3) What I want: 
a) all `.big-block-item`s to be of the same height
b) all `.block-small-item`s to be of the same height. 
4) This way they will always look consistent, irregardless of the screen width and how many of them fit in a line (4, 2 or 1). 
5) The solution works when I open/refresh the page. It just doesn't want to work when I resize. I don't know why.

Comment: I already explained why … On the ready event, you set a _fixed_ height for all those elements. So when you read those element heights back in your resize handler, you will only ever get this one fixed height value back for all elements. The new “maximum” height you are calculating, is the height these elements already _have_. Just because the content might be _overflowing_ that fixed height you set initially, when the element widths change, does not mean that the actual, specified height changes as well.

Comment: - OK, so do you agree I can't do the stuff I want with Flexbox? Just to make sure. 
- If I understand properly, I can't just reuse this code in the resize handler.

Comment: No, same height with flexbox only work for items on the same line, but not when they wrap around. Your JS solution will need an additional wrapper element - so that you can set the fixed height on that wrapper, based on the maximum heights of the elements inside those wrappers. By not slapping a fixed height on these elements themselves, you will still be able to read the _actual_ height their content requires in your resize handler then.

Comment: Good to know all of that! Thanks a lot.